# Lévy-Khintchine formula for Cauchy distribution

Tags: probability-theory

The Lévy-Khintchine formula for the log of the characteristic function of an infinitely divisible random variable is

$$
\Psi(s)=ias + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2s^2 + \int_{\mathbb{R}}(1-e^{isx} + is\mathbb{1}_{|x|<1})d\nu(x)$$

for some $(a,\sigma,\nu)$.

The Cauchy distribution has characteristic function $\exp(-|s|)$.

How can this be rewritten in the form of the Lévy-Khintchine formula?

Comment: You have forgotten to exponentiate the entire right hand side.

Comment: Thanks Alex.  I've made a correction.

Comment: Lévy with an é.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on how you define $\Psi$ (something that you should make clear), your general formula is or is not flawed. For the choice which corresponds to
$$
\Psi(s)=\mathrm ias - \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2s^2 + \int_{\mathbb{R}}(\mathrm e^{\mathrm isx}-1-\mathrm isx\mathbb{1}_{|x|<1})\mathrm d\nu(x),
$$
and for the standard Cauchy distribution,
$$
a=\sigma^2=0,\qquad\mathrm d\nu(x)=|x|^{-2}\mathbf 1_{x\ne0}\mathrm dx.
$$

Comment: thanks im able to redervive that,although i had to use the fact that there is a density for a cauchy rv.